# dynamic .ToObject<CustomClass>() not working as expected

Tags: c#, json, selenium

I have a .json file and a custom class.

I am taking this .json file and putting it in a dynamic variable, so that I can access specific points in the file at run time. See below code

```
private static dynamic elements = null;
public static dynamic Elements { get { return elements; } }

static Settings()
{
    elements = JObject.Parse(Common.GetFile("Elements.json"));
}
```

In the below function, I am using the dynamic variable above in order to identify smaller "chunks" of the .json file. [See Below]

```
public void Login(string pUserName, string pPassword)
{
   dynamic _module = Settings.Elements.Login;

   ElementObject _userName = _module.UserName.ToObject<ElementObject>();
   ElementObject _password = _module.Password.ToObject<ElementObject>();
   ElementObject _loginBTN = _module.LoginButton.ToObject<ElementObject>();

   _userName.OnSendKeys(pUserName);
   _password.OnSendKeys(pPassword);
   _loginBTN.OnClick();
}
```

The issue, is that ElementObject.cs has a constructor that requires the public properties to be populated via the .json script. However, when stepping through debugging, the public properties arn't getting set until after the variable declaration. [See images below]

```
public class ElementObject
{
    public string ClassName;
    public string CssSelector;
    public string Id;
    public string LinkText;
    public string Name;
    public string PartialLinkText;
    public string TagName;
    public string XPath;

    private int index = 0;
    private string finalName = "";
    private string finalClassName = "";

    public ElementObject()
    {
        var _b = new string[] { nameof(ClassName), nameof(CssSelector), nameof(Id), nameof(LinkText), nameof(Name), nameof(PartialLinkText), nameof(TagName), nameof(XPath) };
        var _a = new string[] { ClassName, CssSelector, Id, LinkText, Name, PartialLinkText, TagName, XPath };

        index = Array.IndexOf(_a, _a.FirstOrDefault(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)));
        finalName = _a[index];
        finalClassName = _b[index];
    }
}
```

In the picture below, you can see that I am properly getting the json data.
[image]

In the below picture, by the time we get to the constructor, none of the values are being populated
[image]

In the below picture, you can see that after we stepped out of the constructor, the properties were applied, but the constructor didn't see it applied.
[image]

Comment: This just seems like a really awkward and complex way to deserialise JSON into C# classes.

Comment: The constructor is *the first thing that executes to initialize the instance*. It isn't *possible* to initialize fields before it runs. It's unclear why you would expect this to work. (Disclaimer: this is a lie, it is very much possible in raw IL code. However, you can't do it in C#.)

Comment: Correct, but how do you purpose i convert json object to dynamic classes, with dynamic variables? As far as my knowledge goes, this is the best method. 

I can't just create a bunch of classes, because they can change on the fly.

Comment: Try deserialising into `Dictionary<string, string>` for example, that will give you a bunch of key value pairs which may be closer to what you need.

Comment: Interesting theory. Thanks for your input

Comment: This is expected. Properties of an object doesn't have values until they are set explicitly either from constructor or from outside of object once it is initialized. When you are trying to convert dynamic to ElementObject, constructor is executed first and once the object is initialized it's properties are assigned values. That's why you are seeing the properties values after the object is created. Just to make it simple, if you simply create and object of ElementObject using new keyword then also you will see the null values of properties until you are them explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

I created a work around, after investigation what I wanted doesn't seem to work.

Here is my work around. [See Code Below].

```
public ElementObject() { }

public static ElementObject Create(dynamic pSrcObj)
{
    ElementObject obj = pSrcObj.ToObject<ElementObject>();
    obj.Init();
    return obj;
}

public void Init()
{
    var _b = new string[] { nameof(ClassName), nameof(CssSelector), nameof(Id), nameof(LinkText), nameof(Name), nameof(PartialLinkText), nameof(TagName), nameof(XPath) };
    var _a = new string[] { ClassName, CssSelector, Id, LinkText, Name, PartialLinkText, TagName, XPath };

    index = Array.IndexOf(_a, _a.FirstOrDefault(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)));
    finalName = _a[index];
    finalClassName = _b[index];
}
```

In order for me now to create the object, i create it like this;

```
ElementObject _userName = ElementObject.Create(_module.UserName);
```